# Split Array not same as Defined array with same contents?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

This outputs-BPBPfalse.

I am really confused as to why the boolean is false when the string obviously is the exact same.

Why isnt it BPBPtrue?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class mySplit {

public static void main(String myString[])
{
    String myString1= "BP+Car+Bird";
    String myArray[] = {"BP","Car","Bird"};

    String myArray2[]= myString1.split("\\+");
    String A = myArray[0];
    String B = myArray2[0];

    System.out.print(A);
    System.out.print(B);

    boolean One = (A==B);
    System.out.print(One);

}

}
```

OUTPUT - BPBPfalse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A==B
```

needs to be

```
A.equals(B)
```

because they are different objects.

```
String one = "one";
String two = one;
boolean isEqual = one == two; // TRUE
boolean notTheSameObject = ("one" == one); // FALSE
boolean areEqual = (one.equals("one")); // TRUE String.equals
```

Comment: thank you so much.... you have no idea how much pain that had cause me.... haha thanks

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should flag it as the correct answer